# Transforming a dataframe into a TS in R

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series

I've been trying to transform a dataframe I put together into a Time Series, but for some reason it doesn't work. I am very new to R.

```
    x<-Sales_AEMBG%>%
+   select(Ecriture.DatEcr, Crédit, Mapping)
> names(x)<-c("Dates","Revenue","Mapping")
> str(x)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   15167 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Dates  : POSIXct, format: "2016-01-02" "2016-01-02" "2016-01-02" "2016-01-02" ...
 $ Revenue: num  124065 214631 135810 225293 57804 ...
 $ Mapping: chr  "E.M 1.5 L" "E.M 1.5 L" "E.M 1.5 L" "E.M 1.5 L" ...'
```

When I try to look at the data, here's what I have

```
> head(x)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  Dates               Revenue Mapping  
  <dttm>                <dbl> <chr>    
1 2016-01-02 00:00:00 124065. E.M 1.5 L
2 2016-01-02 00:00:00 214631. E.M 1.5 L
3 2016-01-02 00:00:00 135810. E.M 1.5 L
4 2016-01-02 00:00:00 225293. E.M 1.5 L
5 2016-01-02 00:00:00  57804. E.M 1.5 L
6 2016-01-02 00:00:00 124065. E.M 1.5 L
```

Of course, I tried the as.ts function

```
 > x_xts <- as.ts(x)
Warning message:
In data.matrix(data) : NAs introduced by coercion
> is.ts(x)
[1] FALSE
```

But it keeps telling me that my dataframe is still not recognized as a TS.

What do you suggest ?

Thanks

Comment: A quick search here would find this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29046311/how-to-convert-data-frame-into-time-series

Comment: I notice that your dates are all the same, at least for the first 6 records. You'll have problems converting that data frame into a time series object...

Comment: @Edward if you see my data, you'll find that I have multiple transactions in the same day, and for the same products. So first I need to find how to sum sales by day and product type (there are 5 product types in the total dataframe)

Comment: OK. So do you need help with that ?

Comment: @Edward Yes I do !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added a few more observations to your data.

```
# A tibble: 12 x 3
   Dates               Revenue Mapping  
   <dttm>                <dbl> <chr>    
 1 2016-01-02 00:00:00  124065 E.M 1.5 L
 2 2016-01-02 00:00:00  214631 E.M 1.5 L
 3 2016-01-03 00:00:00  135810 E.M 1.5 L
 4 2016-01-03 00:00:00  225293 E.M 1.5 L
 5 2016-01-05 00:00:00   57804 E.M 1.5 L
 6 2016-01-05 00:00:00  124065 E.M 1.5 L
 7 2016-01-02 00:00:00   24065 E.M 1.5 M
 8 2016-01-02 00:00:00   14631 E.M 1.5 M
 9 2016-01-03 00:00:00   35810 E.M 1.5 M
10 2016-01-03 00:00:00   25293 E.M 1.5 M
11 2016-01-05 00:00:00    7804 E.M 1.5 M
12 2016-01-05 00:00:00   24065 E.M 1.5 M
```

---

First you need to sum the sales by day (`Dates`) and product type (your `Mapping` variable?), and pivot into a wider data format:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

x.sum <- x %>%
  group_by(Mapping, Dates) %>%
  summarise(Revenue=sum(Revenue)) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols=Dates, names_from=Mapping, values_from=Revenue)
```

---

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  Dates               `E,M 1.5 L` `E,M 1.5 M`
  <dttm>                    <dbl>       <dbl>
1 2016-01-02 00:00:00      338696       38696
2 2016-01-03 00:00:00      361103       61103
3 2016-01-05 00:00:00      181869       31869
```

---

Note that I've deliberately omitted Jan 4.

If your time series data has missing days, such as stock prices where financial markets are closed on the weekends, then using the `as.ts` (or `ts`) function won't work. If there are no missing days, then then correct way to convert the data into a time series object ("ts") is to specify the column(s) to convert (`x.sum[,2:3]`) and the start (January 2, 2016) and frequency (daily) of the series.

```
x.ts <- ts(x.sum[,2:3], start=c(2016, 2), frequency=365)
```

Be careful with the start as the second argument depends on the specified frequency. Here, 365 means daily, so the "2" means day 2 of year 2016. If the frequency was monthly, the "2" would mean month 2 of year 2016.

But as I mentioned, `ts` doesn't ignore any missing days. So for this make-up data, if you plotted the time series, then you will get the wrong information.

In this case, other packages such as **xts** and **zoo** can be used to simply the work.

```
library(xts)
x.xts <- xts(x.sum[,2:3], order.by=x.sum$Dates)

plot(x.xts) # Correct results.
```

Other answers about time series can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33128865/starting-a-daily-time-series-in-r) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29046311/how-to-convert-data-frame-into-time-series).

Comment: GREAT ANSWER ! 

Thanks a lot Edward !

Comment: Hello @Edward, I am working with your solution now. All good so far, but I can't figure out how in my case I can decompose the data to apply an ARIMA process. 
Since each year has a different number of days in it, I don't know how to build a summary by year to spot seasonality

Comment: I'm afraid you'll need to start a whole new question. Not because I don't want to help, or I can't help, but because you'll get a lot more response from others. But more importantly, this question is closed.