# How to convert csv into ts in R?

Tags: r

I am beginner with R... I'd like to do Time series series analysis on different kind of prices. I get the data and converted it into csv. However, I am not able to convert them into ts. 
I tried ti use different commands but it did not work out.

Comment: Hi please share some data using ```dput()``` will be helpful to help.and share what you have tried so far.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: Why did you convert the data into csv? __R__ can read many data file formats, including Excel, SPSS, ...

Comment: Did you do a search here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60483201/transforming-a-dataframe-into-a-ts-in-r/, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29046311/how-to-convert-data-frame-into-time-series?noredirect=1&lq=1, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33128865/starting-a-daily-time-series-in-r?noredirect=1&lq=1 may help you.